# How to parse given date string using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I want the following date string to be formatted using moment.js but it gives invalid date.

```
var dateString = '2/17/2016 12:16PM GMT-05:00';
var pattern = 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mma ZZ';
var testDate = moment(dateString).format(pattern); //Invalid Date
```

How to parse it correctly or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: `PM` makes this an invalid date. Check it with `new Date('2/17/2016 12:16PM GMT-05:00')`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use pattern as second parameter in moment function

```
var testDate = moment(dateString, pattern)
```

more here in the docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: Thanks entio. If you think the question may help someone, you may upvote the question.

Comment: @sarsjits If You think answer can help anyone, do as You suggested with the answer, man.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```js
var dateString = '2/17/2016 12:16PM GMT-05:00';
var pattern = 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mma ZZ';
var testDate = moment(dateString, "MM/DD/YYYY h:mmA -hh:mm").format(pattern);
```