# Need help parsing php date using moment.js

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

My PHP script is giving me following date:

```
"Friday, 31-Mar-17 07:45:47 UTC"
```

I want to parse this date using `moment.js` and I want to store each parsed token into separate JavaScript variable. How can I do this in `moment.js`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse given date string using moment.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450227/how-to-parse-given-date-string-using-moment-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse it. Then you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) or [getters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) to get each parsed token:

```js
var m = moment.utc("Friday, 31-Mar-17 07:45:47 UTC", "dddd, DD-MMM-YY HH:mm:ss Z");
console.log(m.format());
var dayOfWeek = m.format('dddd'); // Friday
var dayOfMonth = m.date(); // 31
var shortMonthName = m.format('MMM'); // Mar
var shortYear = m.format('YY'); // 17
var minutes = m.minutes(); // 45

console.log(dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, shortMonthName, shortYear, minutes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```