# Parse and format custom date string Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to extract month and year from a custom date string
`Wed Dec 24 00:00:00 -0800 2014` using Moment.js.

I found this previous answer: [How to parse given date string using moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450227/how-to-parse-given-date-string-using-moment-js) but the accepted answer is throwing an error.

Thought the syntax would be:

`var date = moment("Wed Dec 24 00:00:00 -0800 2014","ddd MMM DD HH:MM:SS ZZ YYYY").format('dd');`

`console.log(date);` expected output is `24` but instead returns `Invalid Date`.

Any ideas how to pull date out of the given date string? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a strange date string format. Are you in control of how it gets generated?

Comment: nope im not, its an API response. Agreed, though, its unfortunate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To anyone interested, the solution was making `HH:MM:SS` lower case and `dd` uppercase.

Final string and format was `var date = moment("Wed Dec 24 00:00:00 -0800 2014","ddd MMM DD hh:mm:ss ZZ YYYY").format('DD');`.

Comment: You need to keep `HH` in upper case to maintain the 24 hour format.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this in a js fiddle and it provided me with 24, I think the issue is you didn't capitalize your `.format('dd')`

```
var date = moment("Wed Dec 24 00:00:00 -0800 2014","ddd MMM DD HH:MM:SS ZZ YYYY").format('DD');
alert(date);
```

Comment: gave it a shot but it still returns `Invalid Date`. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Very weird, here is the fiddle I tried it in if you would like to see http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/110437/ . The only thing I can possibly think of if it works there and not for you is maybe the version of moment.js you are using? The version the fiddle is using 2.2.1. Good luck!

Comment: You actually got half of it for me and pointed me in the right direction. I posted the full answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: you should use "mm" and "ss" for respectively the minutes and the seconds. You used "MM" (month) and "SS" (???)